# How to do Style to jquery code

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add some style elements to my jquery code.

My objective is to be able to position a box absolutely after the person has scrolled down the screen after 200px.

The box reduces in size after a 200px scroll but i want to have the ability to position the box where i want.

Here is my code.

Can some one guide me on where I am going wrong.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LLbAu/1/)

```
  $( window ).scroll(function() {
     if($(window).scrollTop() > 200){
       $('#profile-pic-bg').css({'width': '50'});
        $("#profile-pic-bg").css({ position: "absolute", top: "20", left:"5" });
     }else{
         $('#profile-pic-bg').css({'width': '145'});
     }

});
```

Comment: how is java related here? please remove java tag

Comment: I didn't understand the point here, your code works fine unless you mean that you want a "floating box"
PS: Remove Java Tag.

Comment: Jquery is a library from java??

Comment: Oh jquery is from java rocking man...like ur comment..

Comment: @user2965875, Jquery Is a `Javascript` library, Java is a thing, and Javascript is something else.

Comment: @user2965875 Jquery is a framework with base in javascript, not java.

Comment: Somewhat off topic but [Java and Javascript are similar like Car and Carpet are similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: ok . i have removed the tag

Comment: What a useless discussion, just change the tag and be done with it.

Comment: Ok thanks for your java comments, can anybody help me with positioning my element absolutely though? my code doesnt seem to work?

Comment: your fiddle seems to work, if you inspect the element after you have scrolled 200px you will see it gets absolutely positioned.  just add px to your top and left (or remove the quotes)

Answer (score 4):

Remove the quotes from the `top` and `left` property values, or they wont work:

```
$("#profile-pic-bg").css({ position: "absolute", top: 20, left: 5 });
```

Comment: `top: "20", left:"5"` -> `top: 20, left: 5`

Comment: Yeah I seen... thought you meant the actual properties, but you meant the property values

Comment: @David also if he wants it with quote then he should use px like "20px"

Comment: @C-Link true, but unless you are using other units than pixels it doesn’t make a difference. I prefer integers, some prefer strings...

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
     if($(window).scrollTop() > 200){

        $("#profile-pic-bg").css({ 
            "position": "absolute", 
            "top": "20px", 
            "left":"5px" ,
            "width":'50px'
        });
     }else{
         $('#profile-pic-bg').css({'width': '145px'});
     }

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LLbAu/2/)

Comment: Thanks for this ! great help. Can you show me how you would add style to the box width 145px too?

Comment: if scroll return again 200 below the height is set it to the selector see fiddle

Comment: if you check the fiddle the and move back up the screen the box does not pick up the original style. it moves out of place.

Comment: "background-image": "url('../img/assets/profile-pic-bg.png') 0px 0px no-repeat !important;"

Comment: I have tried to add a background image into the jquery but its not working? have i done somthing wrong?